# Bootstrap 4 - Cropping image into a circle - landscape photos are not cropped properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to crop a photo of any size into 120 x 120 px.  Bootstrap doesn't come with a good circle crop, so I'm using a combination of `img-fluid` from bootstrap 4 and `overflow:hidden` + `border-radius` to achieve this.

This works fine for portrait photos (height > width), but for landscape photos [like this](https://i.gyazo.com/da27f072059db48590e3b9da9d7789c2.jpg), the result [is this](https://i.gyazo.com/309794c589a6dbc8e561f31693ed6a0f.png).

HTML:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; height:120px; width:120px; border-radius:50%;">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="picture.png" alt='Agent picture' />
</div>
```

How do I crop landscape photos properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will fit your needs but you could use the `background-image` property to accomplish this. Here is a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOxyGV).

HTML:

```
<div class="agent-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.agent-image{

    background-image:url("https://i.gyazo.com/da27f072059db48590e3b9da9d7789c2.jpg");
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  I would prefer to use <img> as it feels more natural (probably a stupid assumption), but whatever works works!

Comment: There probably is a way to get one with `<img>` to work, though it might be more work than this, also with this you can use that handy dandy position property to use the part of the img you want

Comment: I did some work and realized that a lot of my images are no longer responsively-sized because `img-fluid` from Bootstrap (which responsively sizes images) only applies to `<img>`.  I'm going to backtrack and see if I can find a solution for <img>

Comment: That is probably due to the staticly assigned width and height